# Inserting items in map using new initialization list syntax

Tags: c++11, dictionary, insert, initializer-list

I was playing with C++11, and I found a very useful way to insert values in a map (unordered and/or multimap):

```
map<unsigned, string> test;
test.insert({1, "abc"});
```

Although this code is working (compiled with GCC 4.8 or Clang 3.2), I have some issues about it. The `insert()` has 6 signatures basically where we are interested on

```
1. pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
2. template <class P> pair<iterator,bool> insert (P&& val);
3. void insert (initializer_list<value_type> il);
```

The first two take a `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>` type object when the last takes a list of then. So, theoretically, the code

```
test.insert({1, "abc"});
```

is using the second `insert()` version/signature, where it uses the C++11 uniform initialization to build the pair and thus uses this pair as `lvalue`. This can be "interpreted" as

```
test.insert(pair<const unsigned, string> {1, "abc"});
```

Note that we also can do

```
test.insert(pair<const unsigned, string>(1, "abc"));
```

or

```
test.insert(make_pair(1, "abc"));
```

but the first version seems more natural. Is there some major problem with this approach? Some possible conflict with the list initializer version?

Comment: It's even easier to use `test.emplace(1, "abc");`.

Comment: It should use the first version of `insert` with your initial code. The second one is not even callable with a braced init list.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In fact, the second "version" has been compiled both for G++ 4.8 and Clang++ 3.2, and it has been worked fine to me. My main issue s with respect to the possible conflict between versions 2 and 3.

Comment: @KennyTM I missed `emplace()` completely. In fact, it's easier and clearer, and, IHO, less error-prone. Thanks!

Comment: @an_drade if you have conflicts between 2 and 3, i recommend sending a bug report to them.